Keep mouse position relative to element when scaling it up and down
I'm working on a timeline component with ReactJS.
The timeline is a Div element, and it has a container element inside of it.
The container contains many smaller elements which represent events in the timeline.
When the mouse wheel is used, the element should zoom in/out (which works), and whatever is under the mouse, should remain exactly there while zooming (doesn't work).
The somewhat works, however the closer the mouse is to the right of the viewport the displacement compensation gets worse.
This is the basic logic for the compensation (its part of a react component):
const timeline = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [timeScale, setTimeScale] = useState(time.month);
const [leftOffset, setLeftOffset] = useState(0);
const [positions, setPositions] = useState<Position[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setPositions(
        timelineToPositions(props.data, timeline.current!.clientWidth, timeScale),
    );
}, [props.data, timeScale]);

function handleZoom(event: WheelEvent) {
    // Prevent the page from scrolling.
    // TODO: only do this if the timeline is focused.
    if (event.deltaY === 0) return;
    event.preventDefault();

    const startWidth = timeline.current!.scrollWidth;
    const factor = (startWidth + event.deltaY) / startWidth;
    const clientX = event.clientX;

    setLeftOffset((left) => {
        const displacement = (clientX - left) * (1 - factor);
        return Math.floor(left - displacement);
    });

    setTimeScale((scale) => scale * factor);
}

You can find a demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8yiddr?file=src%2FTimeline.tsx
